# MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 3110239 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException Error

Tags: java, android

I have making one Application which is just play song from a URL.This url will be Created using NanoHTTP.This URL is nothing but combination of Device ip and Port Address.

**Code Specification**
I have just Receive this URL as Message.One i Get URL and Provide this URL to Media Player class.

```
  try {

                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if (handler != null) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(notification);

                }
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                // String url =  URLEncoder.encode(commandHelper.getSongDetails().getSongURL(), "UTF-8");
                String url = commandHelper.getSongDetails().getSongURL();
                Log.e("Tag", "Receiving Url  Data ::" + url);// Song URL ::: http://192.168.1.160:8085/
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                DebugLog.e("Value ::" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and My url is like http://192.168.1.160:8085/

**Issue**

Everything going fine but while I start Media Player than get following error

- W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 3110239 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException

and Also my Device Hanging UP and Device is not Responding.
I have also try mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(),mediaPlayer.prepare(FileDescriptor) for handle this error but I get same result.

**Note**

This issue is OS Specific it's Only happend in 5.0(LOLIPOP) OS.

Please help me if any one have proper solution about this problem.i Hardly try to solve this problem but i getting same error.so please help to solve this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem :( any help?

Answer (score 8):

For me this problem was happening when a data source was used twice. I fixed it by disabling caching. The problem was that caching was saving bad length or position info or something. Not sure why maybe because of compression.

I only had this problem on particular mp3 files(I'm still researching why only these files were affected).

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "audio/mp3"); // change content type if necessary
headers.put("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
headers.put("Status", "206");
headers.put("Cache-control", "no-cache");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(yourContentUrl);
player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri, headers);
```

Comment: Were you able to find why this was happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's link to the source (and the OS).

I found an explication for my case : codec MPEG-4 ODSM, MPEG-4 SDSM.
With another source (only H.264, AAC), it's working.

Linked question : [Android Marshmallow "Can't play this video" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611368/android-marshmallow-cant-play-this-video-error)
Formats supported by Android : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

So the solution is to try another source or to re-encode you media.