# Android webview not playing video in Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: android, html, webview, html5-video, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to play video in webview with html5 video tag, with android lollipop 5.1.1 its work perfectly but with Marshmallow 6.0.1 I get just the first frame (its look like the video is freeze)

What is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: i think some google default issues is there..refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611368/android-marshmallow-cant-play-this-video-error

Comment: are you getting any error in log

Comment: try with android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest

Comment: @SunilP I get error from my html code: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null , When i try to do :  buffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());

Comment: @KingofMasses This is not work for me, thank.